# Logstash - Filter on Type

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

This is my Logstash configuration file. I have multiple configuration files that parse out different CSV files and I want each CSV to go into a separate index. I am trying to do this by using type at the input filter and then use the conditionals to see if the type matches and if so, send it to the correct index. The only problem is, I must be missing something since it doesn't work!

```
input {
    file {
            path => "/reports/device-availability.csv"
            start_position => "beginning"
            type => "device-availability"
    }
}

filter {

    if [type] == "device-availability" {
            csv {
                    separator => ","
                    columns => ["Company","Date","Device","IP Address","Device Type","Availability","Uptime"]
            }
            date {
                    match => ["Date", "MMM-yy", "yy-MMM", "MM/yy", "M/yy"]
                    locale => "en"
            }
            mutate {
                    convert => { "Availability"  => "float" }
                    convert => { "Uptime" => "float" }
            }
    }
}

output {
    if [type] == "device-availability" {
            elasticsearch {
                            action => "index"
                            hosts => "localhost"
                            index => "device-availability"
                            workers => 1
            }

            stdout {
            }

            file {
                    path => "/output/logstash/device-availability.log"
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw that the file was never being re-read and in the logs I saw that logstash stored the last position in "$HOME/.sincedb" so I updated the input section to reset that every time it ran and I start to see the data polling again. I will test the filter and output functions now.                                                                      input {
    file {
            path => "/reports/device-availability.csv"
            start_position => "beginning"
            type => "device-availability"
            sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

Comment: Got it working! That was the problem, the file was never being re-read. Thanks all!

Comment: Nice one on fixing this. You can specify the sincedb path in the input filter and push it out do /dev/null for testing purposes. When in prod, move it to a central location so its easily accessible.